# Vim: set "cursor keys" hjkl to wasd

Tags: vi, vimrc, gvim, vim

I wish to overwrite/remap the basic `vi`/`vim` (and `gvim`) "cursor keys" **hjkl** to the ordinary "gamer layout" **wasd** (w-up, a-left, s-down, d-right). Moreover: I know that "w", "a", "s" and "d" are important keys in `vim` so I came up with the idea to remap **hjkl** to **ALT + wasd**.

Comment: Start playing rogue-like games such as [nethack](http://www.nethack.org/).  You'll quickly learn the **hjkl** keys.

Comment: cross posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182952/vim-set-cursor-keys-hjkl-to-wasd

Answer (score 2):

On most installation I have come across:

- <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>something</kbd>

is the *same* as:

- <kbd>ESC</kbd> (release after press) <kbd>something</kbd>

So, vim commands are always "ALT-Prefixed".

But, as you have found out in the meantime, there is a way to specify this key combination in the vimrc.

Answer (score 1):

Question had been solved at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182952/vim-set-cursor-keys-hjkl-to-wasd/38184185?noredirect=1#comment63794517_38184185):

Adding

```
noremap <Esc>a h
noremap <Esc>s j
noremap <Esc>w k
noremap <Esc>d l
```

to `.vimrc` solved the problem.